# cvToImgMsg equivalent in Indigo?

Tags: cv-bridge, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ROS Indigo on Ubuntu Trusty, and I'm following along with this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages. However, if I go along with the code exactly, catkin_make tells me that cv_bridge/CvBridge.h doesn't exist. If I replace CvBridge with cv_bridge, it has no problem finding the header file, but I get a problem with the following line:

```
  sensor_msgs::ImagePtr msg = sensor_msgs::cv_bridge::cvToImgMsg(image.Ipl(), "bgr8");
```

The message I get is "error: ‘sensor_msgs::cv_bridge’ has not been declared". Is CvBridge.h deprecated as of Indigo? If so, how do I accomplish what cvToImgMsg is supposed to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194528/cvtoimgmsg-equivalent-in-indigo?/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like that tutorial is 4 years old, so sadly looks like the API has been broken since then.

If you take a look at the [code api](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/cv_bridge/html/c++/), you can see the correct method to call and the namespace as well. You should be able to call the .toImageMsg() method directly on the CvImage type.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-08**:
This tutorial looks more up to date http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-08**:
CvBridge.h was deprecated in Fuerte or Groovy, and was removed in Hydro. The cv_bridge tutorials are up to date, but I guess this tutorial didn't get updated along with the others.